# How to make .exe files of yii2 application

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have designed a CRUD application in yii2 using model, view and controller. Now I want that this application should be used by users online. How should we do that?
Whether we should make .exe files or host this application?

Comment: you should install  the framework  on a machine with websever, php  and daatabase installed http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html  ..not exe .. just php

Comment: On every user computer, I should install yii2 basic app, xampp server and import the database? and should paste the created application files into their respective basic folder once installed manually? I wanted to make it online to be used.

Comment: No .. on client  you use only a web browser .for accessing web app  . the components mentioned  above must be installe on a web server only  .. acessibile by web

Comment: Currently I have this CRUD application on my laptop. It is just use locally by entering url as localhost/basic/web/index.php?r= How will the other users access them?

Comment: You must install the application on a server  (web server ...)  local or on internet  ..

Comment: How to install the application on web server?

Comment: take a look using   google   .. is a bit too broad as question

Comment: I have installed the XAMPP server and also yii2 basic app. Now how should  i make this local application as online to be used by the users?

Comment: if your XAMPP server is accessible by internet you can simply use the link for access the page using eg:your_doman/basic/web/index.php?r=  instead of localhost ... if is not acessible by internet you must publish on a  internet accessible server  .. take a  look for hosting service  ..